# What kind of gate(s) can I use for this logic?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm trying to combine two digital inputs to get the following output. What kind of gate(s) can I use to get this? I know that no standard logic gate would work. 'X' means doesn't matter.

```
IN-1    IN-2    OUT
0       0       0
0       1       1
1       X       0
```

Comment: One inverter, one AND gate. For just one way, there are others.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by ‘just one way’

Comment: ie. one invertor, one NOR gate...

Comment: you have to perform (A'B)... which gates would u use?

Comment: Do you know anything about Boolean logic/algebra? Like can you get a Boolean expression out of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a circuit like this with only two inputs, it would make this a little easier to analyze if you expand the X:

```
IN-1 IN-2 OUT
0    0    0
0    1    1
1    0    0
1    1    0
```

Since there is only one term resulting in a "1", you can write a Boolean expression describing solely that line. In this case, this means (!IN-1) AND IN-2. You can construct a circuit to compute this using an AND gate, with an inverter on the IN-1 input.

Comment: But OP's question asks for a logic gate rather than a Boolean expression...

Comment: Even though finding a circuit from that expression should be straightforward, edited for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for editing, that now directly answers the question asked. ('Straightforward' makes a presumption about the stage of learning of the OP and of future readers here.)

Comment: Or (!IN_2 NOR IN_1), which would generally make more sense if you're the sort of person who has spare logic gates hanging around.

Answer (score 2):

This is an AND gate with one inverted input (or a NOR gate with the other input inverted).

There are several standard logic devices that can implement this function directly, i.e., [74xx58](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc1g58), [74xx97](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc1g97), [74xx98](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc1g98), and [74xx99](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc1g99):

[image: AND gate with one inverted input]